# How do I add data to an existing model in Django?

Tags: python, django

Currently, I am writing up a bit of a product-based CMS as my first project.

Here is my question. How can I add additional data (products) to my Product model?

I have added '/admin/products/add' to my urls.py, but I don't really know where to go from there. How would i build both my view and my template? Please keep in mind that I don't really know all that much Python, and i am very new to Django

How can I do this all without using this existing django admin interface.

Comment: Your question title might be a bit misleading; model is generally used in place of model class. I think "How do I create a new model instance via views" is a better title.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will want to wire your URL to the Django [create_object generic view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-create-update-create-object), and pass it either "model" (the model you want to create) or "form_class" (a customized [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#topics-forms-modelforms) class).  There are a number of [other arguments](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-create-update-create-object) you can also pass to override default behaviors.

Sample URLconf for the simplest case:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.views.generic.create_update import create_object

from my_products_app.models import Product

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/products/add/$', create_object, {'model': Product}))
```

Your template will get the context variable "form", which you just need to wrap in a <form> tag and add a submit button.  The simplest working template (by default should go in "my_products_app/product_form.html"):

```
<form action="." method="POST">
  {{ form }}
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="add">
</form>
```

Note that your Product model must have a get_absolute_url method, or else you must pass in the post_save_redirect parameter to the view.  Otherwise it won't know where to redirect to after save.

Answer (score -1):

This topic is covered in [Django tutorials](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/Tutorials).

Answer (score -2):

Follow the Django tutorial for setting up the "admin" part of an application. This will allow you to modify your database.

[Django Admin Setup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial02/)

Alternatively, you can just connect directly to the database using the standard tools for whatever database type you are using.